# macro (newcommand) Why some text is not getting in the output ?

Tags: macros

I want to repeat some text and tables on the same page. I am trying the code given below, but it is printing only once and then again it is not printing the ruler at the end. The complete code is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=2cm,
 bottom=5mm,
 }

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
  \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
  \kern#2 % space after the rule
  \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{1\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\newcommand\insertBigText[1]{
 \noindent\textbox{\hfil \Large{\textbf{#1}}\hfil} \\

\myrule[1pt][2pt]
\vspace{5pt}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{
  \begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|*{2}{[2pt]X[c,m]|}}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 1}} & \vspace{5mm}\\ \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 2}} &  \vspace{5mm} \\\hline 
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 3 }} &  \vspace{5mm}\\\hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 4}} & some more text\\\hline

    \end{tabu}}
\hfill
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{
\centering
  \begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|*{1}{[2pt]X[c,m]|}}
     \textbf{string 1} \\\hline 
     \textbf{string 2} \\\hline 
      string 3 \\\hline
    \end{tabu}}
\end{table}

\myrule[1pt][2pt] % strange! doesn't get printed at all
} %end \newcommand\insertBigText[1]{

% ------------ document start
\begin{document}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt}  
\insertBigText{receipt} % only this part gets printed
\vspace{2mm}
\noindent\textbox{\hfil \Large{\textbf{counterfoil}}\hfil} \\ % strange! doesn't get printed at all
\myrule[1pt][2pt] % strange! doesn't get printed at all
\insertBigText{counterfoil} % strange! doesn't get printed at all


\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the line   `\kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line` in your definition. Besides this, there are some other bad practices such as using ` \\ ` followed by blank lines.

Comment: To follow up Gonzalo's comment, in half the cases here `\prevdepth` is -1000pt which is a big negative skip to insert. Also `\Large` like all size commands does not take a `{}` argument.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for pointing this out. I removed that line and it worked fine. Can you explain why this is so? Also turn your comment into answer. I will accept it.

Comment: prevdepth=-1000pt is a special built in flag in tex-the-program for start of a vertical list.

Comment: @jitm234 I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is with the line

```
\kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
```

in the definition of `\myrule`. To understand the problem, look at what *The TeXbook* (double dangerous-bend at the bottom of page 79) says about `\prevdepth`:

> However, `\prevdepth` is set to the sentinel value `−1000pt`
> at the beginning of a vertical list, or just after a rule box; this serves to suppress the next interline glue.

So the second time you use your command, `\prevdepth` is `-1000pt` and you do a vertical skip of `-1000pt` (approximately `-14in`!) before typesetting the material; the material, obviously is pushed upwards, out of the page.

Besides this, there are other problems with the code, such as using `\\` followed by a blank line and using `\Large` as a command with arguments. I fixed them (but perhaps adjustments will be needed, depending on your actual intent).

Here's a reduced version of the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=2cm,
 bottom=5mm,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here%
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
  \kern#2 % space after the rule
  \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{1\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\newcommand\insertBigText[1]{
\noindent\textbox{\hfil{\Large\textbf{#1}}\hfil}\par
\myrule[1pt][2pt]
\vspace{5pt}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{%
  \begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|*{2}{[2pt]X[c,m]|}}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 1}} & \vspace{5mm}\\ \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 2}} &  \vspace{5mm} \\\hline 
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 3 }} &  \vspace{5mm}\\\hline
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{text 4}} & some more text\\\hline
    \end{tabu}}
\hfill
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{%
\centering
  \begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|*{1}{[2pt]X[c,m]|}}
     \textbf{string 1} \\\hline 
     \textbf{string 2} \\\hline 
      string 3 \\\hline
    \end{tabu}}
\end{table}
\myrule[1pt][2pt]%
}

\begin{document}

\insertBigText{receipt}
\vspace{2mm}
\myrule[1pt][2pt]
\insertBigText{counterfoil}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

You'll still get two warnings from `geometry`:

```
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction. `width'
(597.50787pt) is ignored.

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction. `height' 
(845.04684pt) is ignored.
```

so you will need to check the settings used.

### Update

As **egreg** notices in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229404/macro-newcommand-why-some-text-is-not-getting-in-the-output/229410#comment541657_229410) you can use a conditional test to safely have the `\kern` in your definition:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here%
  \ifdim\prevdepth>-1000pt\kern\prevdepth\fi
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
  \kern#2 % space after the rule
  \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}
```

Comment: One could do `\ifdim\prevdepth>-1000pt\kern\prevdepth\fi`

Comment: @egreg I added your suggestion to my answer. Thanks.